# FIREBASE - reauthenticateWithCredential and Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been having some problems with the "reauthenticateWithCredential" method.
I need to be able to delete a user from my application and erase some database nodes with user's data.

The problem is, whenever I call "reauthenticateWithCredential" and receive a positive promise, all future attempts to access my firebase database are simply ignored...no logs or permission errors are shown on the browser console.
I've tried signing the user again, calling other functions outside of the reauth function, restarting Firebase after the reauth but none of these worked.

Comment: use this for Brazilian https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The question need some more details. 
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)